# Campus vs premises

Tags: word-difference

What are the differences between campus and premises? For example if we say [Apple Campus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Campus) and if we say Apple premises.

I checked the Oxford Living Dictionaries website and the meanings seem to be the same:

> **campus**: the grounds and buildings of a university or college.
>     *North American* The grounds of a school, hospital, or other institution.
>
> **premises**: A house or building, together with its land and outbuildings, occupied by a business or considered in an official context.

Comment: Welcome back! As a reminder, however, questions on stack Exchange are expected to demonstrate some effort at basic initial research. For example, did you look up *campus* and *premises* in a dictionary? If so, which ones, and why were those definitions inadequate?

Comment: @choster https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/premises - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/campus

Comment: I have edited your post to include the required information; if I have misrepresented anything, please feel free to roll it back and [edit] it to provide the appropriate context.

Answer (score 5):

The principal implication of "campus" is that it's an area with multiple buildings, similar to a university, college, or school.

[Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/campus) defines:

> 1: the grounds and buildings of a university, college, or school.
>
> 3: grounds that resemble a campus 
>   *a hospital campus 
>
>   a landscaped corporate campus*

Premises, on the other hand, can just be a single building, or even just part of a building with its associated grounds.

[Merriam-Webster again](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/premises)

> b : a building or part of a building usually with its appurtenances (such as grounds)

Comment: I think that you have not completely answered OP's question. Is there any difference between "Apple Campus" and "Apple premises in Cupertino"? Other dictionaries point that premises can be multiple buildings too.

Comment: In my experience "premises" is little used except in a legal context, or in the set phrases "on/off the premises" - which are originially legal. It may be different in North America.

Comment: @ColinFine American here, I very rarely hear of premises other than the context-dependent phrase "the premises", or in legal contexts as you mention. All the talk of "The Apple premises" is comprehensible, but extremely weird. That said, to me "campus" is only used in that context because Apple says so, not because I have an intuitive grasp on what area is being described and I consider it a campus.